Compute a new column to increment/decrement by 1 per row, in respect to a certain row set with a condition
I would like to increment/decrement by 1 per row, when the starting point (0) is set by a condition in a specific row.
Example
Consider the following my_table:
WITH my_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (DATE '2023-02-01', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-03-22', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-03-30', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-06-10', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-06-11', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-07-03', 'green'),
        (DATE '2023-07-09', 'green'),
        (DATE '2024-01-11', 'green'),
        (DATE '2024-02-11', 'yellow'), -- <~~~ I want this row to be my reference 
        (DATE '2024-02-12', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2024-02-13', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2024-02-14', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2022-10-20', 'blue'),
        (DATE '2022-10-21', 'blue'),
        (DATE '2022-10-22', 'blue')
    ) AS t(my_date, color)
)

I want to create a new column called relative_idx, that will have the value of 0 where my_date = DATE('2024-02-11') AND color = 'yellow'. The rest of the records in relative_idx will have a value in relation to the 0.
Right now, I only know how to do:
SELECT my_date,
       color,
       IF(my_date = DATE('2024-02-11') AND color = 'yellow', 0, NULL) AS relative_idx
FROM my_table; 

-- my_date   |color |relative_idx|
-- ----------+------+------------+
-- 2023-02-01|red   |        NULL|
-- 2023-03-22|red   |        NULL|
-- 2023-03-30|red   |        NULL|
-- 2023-06-10|red   |        NULL|
-- 2023-06-11|red   |        NULL|
-- 2023-07-03|green |        NULL|
-- 2023-07-09|green |        NULL|
-- 2024-01-11|green |        NULL|
-- 2024-02-11|yellow|           0|
-- 2024-02-12|yellow|        NULL|
-- 2024-02-13|yellow|        NULL|
-- 2024-02-14|yellow|        NULL|
-- 2022-10-20|blue  |        NULL|
-- 2022-10-21|blue  |        NULL|
-- 2022-10-22|blue  |        NULL|

But my desired output is:



my_date
color
relative_idx




2023-02-01
red
-8


2023-03-22
red
-7


2023-03-30
red
-6


2023-06-10
red
-5


2023-06-11
red
-4


2023-07-03
green
-3


2023-07-09
green
-2


2024-01-11
green
-1


2024-02-11
yellow
0


2024-02-12
yellow
1


2024-02-13
yellow
2


2024-02-14
yellow
3


2022-10-20
blue
4


2022-10-21
blue
5


2022-10-22
blue
6



I use AWS Athena which relies on Trino SQL.

WITH my_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (DATE '2023-02-01', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-03-22', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-03-30', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-06-10', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-06-11', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-07-03', 'green'),
        (DATE '2023-07-09', 'green'),
        (DATE '2024-01-11', 'green'),
        (DATE '2024-02-11', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2024-02-12', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2024-02-13', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2024-02-14', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2022-10-20', 'blue'),
        (DATE '2022-10-21', 'blue'),
        (DATE '2022-10-22', 'blue')
    ) AS t(my_date, color)
),
    my_table_with_idx AS (
        SELECT *, row_number() OVER() AS relative_idx
        FROM my_table
),  
    reference_row AS (
        SELECT relative_idx
        FROM my_table_with_idx
        WHERE my_date = date '2024-02-11'
        AND color = 'yellow'
)
SELECT *
     , relative_idx - (SELECT * FROM reference_row) AS relative_idx
FROM my_table_with_idx


I found a way to do it, but will be very happy to learn other (hopefully simpler/elegant) approaches.
WITH my_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (DATE '2023-02-01', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-03-22', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-03-30', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-06-10', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-06-11', 'red'),
        (DATE '2023-07-03', 'green'),
        (DATE '2023-07-09', 'green'),
        (DATE '2024-01-11', 'green'),
        (DATE '2024-02-11', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2024-02-12', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2024-02-13', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2024-02-14', 'yellow'),
        (DATE '2022-10-20', 'blue'),
        (DATE '2022-10-21', 'blue'),
        (DATE '2022-10-22', 'blue')
    ) AS t(my_date, color)
),

temp_1 AS (
SELECT my_date,
       color,
       IF(my_date = DATE('2024-02-11') AND color = 'yellow', 0, NULL) AS relative_idx,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn
FROM my_table
),

temp_2 AS (
SELECT any_value(rn) FILTER(WHERE relative_idx = 0) AS rn_ref
FROM temp_1
)

SELECT my_date,
       color,
       rn - rn_ref AS relative_idx
FROM temp_1
CROSS JOIN temp_2;

-- my_date   |color |relative_idx|
-- ----------+------+------------+
-- 2023-02-01|red   |          -8|
-- 2023-03-22|red   |          -7|
-- 2023-03-30|red   |          -6|
-- 2023-06-10|red   |          -5|
-- 2023-06-11|red   |          -4|
-- 2023-07-03|green |          -3|
-- 2023-07-09|green |          -2|
-- 2024-01-11|green |          -1|
-- 2024-02-11|yellow|           0|
-- 2024-02-12|yellow|           1|
-- 2024-02-13|yellow|           2|
-- 2024-02-14|yellow|           3|
-- 2022-10-20|blue  |           4|
-- 2022-10-21|blue  |           5|
-- 2022-10-22|blue  |           6|

